# Postgresql: How can I create a view where I see a percentage of the rows of a table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table named *students* with columns (id,name) with 15 rows.

How can I make a view where with a variable I can specify that I want to see the 50% of the rows of the table students?

I know that to make a view this is the code:

> create or replace view view_students as select * from students

I would really appreciate your help

Comment: Views cannot use parameters. You can make a set returning function though.

Comment: Can you help me please with the idea of the code? @stickybit I'm new in postgresql

Comment: Use a search engine. There is lot of documentation and examples out there.

Comment: Why a view? If you want a random sample, use `select * from students tablesample sytem (50)`

Comment: Which 50% do you want to see? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a query you can limit your response. This will do a round up ( you can't return a half row ;) ) Inside the limit you can count the rows and devided by 2 to get the 50%

```
SELECT * FROM students
LIMIT (SELECT COUNT(*)/2 FROM students)
```

Comment: Using `tablesample` would be way more efficient

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you explain? Like to learn ;)